# How to find the first and last days of the calendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, kendo-ui

I created a Kendo UI calendar, as shown below, and I was wondering how I could get the first and last days displayed on the calendar.

[image]

Here I want to get the first day (25th Aug 2013), and the last day (5th October 2013) from the above calendar. How can I get them?

Here is my code:

```
var cal = $("#calendar").data("kendoCalendar");
var first = $("tbody > tr:first > td:first > a", cal._table).data("value");
var last = $("tbody > tr:last > td:last > a", cal._table).data("value");
```

From the above code I can get the first day, but the last day comes back as null.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Your code works here](http://jsfiddle.net/sLxhg/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/39QPT/1/ this code is almost working for me. But there is a small bug in this. it is returning wrong month for every selection. In your example it is showing first day as 30th May 2013 instead of 30th June 2013. And last day as 10th July 2013 instead of 10th Aug 2013. Any idea?

Comment: this is because the first month January is considered as 0 in your plugin....do it like this....
Add replaceAt function
`String.prototype.replaceAt=function(index, character) {
      return this.substr(0, index) + character + this.substr(index+character.length);
   }`  

your code...

`myNewDate = myDate.replaceAt(myDate.indexOf('/')+1, parseInt(myDate.split('/')[1])+1+"")`